# Check if Docker volume-mounted path is on HDD or SSD?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, ssd, storage, bind-mount

In Linux, it is relatively easy to determine whether a drive is an HDD or SSD. However, is there a method to achieve the same result when you only have a path?

I need to check, from within a Docker container, whether a path (which is volume-mounted) is located on an SSD or HDD. Since I don't have direct access to the drive itself.

The only thing I can think of would be to do some benchmarks on the path, and decide from the resulting timings if it is rotational storage or not.

But I would like to know if there is a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Possibly it is neither. When I get such questions, I would go back and check why do I need such information, especially under docker. If it is about speed: test it. Random access speed: test that, etc. Check capabilities not the underlying technology (which will change)

Comment: You lose the disk information when you mount so you just have filesystem. So no luck. Can you create any files or set environment variables on host where the disk is mounted? It can just be a key value checking to determine the type of your disk. Of course, you should trust your host that the value is correct.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi My container launches a VM using QEMU, and I need to provide it with the information if the virtual disk is on rotational or non-rotational storage, so that QEMU can pass this information to the Guest OS. So yes I need that information otherwise the disk type is incorrectly inside the VM.

Comment: @strboul Yes I can let users set this manually using a Docker environment variable, but most people just copy the compose file example and don't bother customizing all the values. So if I could detect this automaticly it would be more foolproof than relying on the end-user.

Comment: @Maestro: why? That information is in any case wrong inside QEMU, so you do not need to pass such information. Again: if you think it is relevant for some application, just measure the timing, and then tell QEMU the kind of drive. But then you should also provide all drive information (manufacturer, model, size, etc.). or just lie. You can have very fast rotational drive (a lot of cache) or a very slow USB-1 non-rotational external disk. What about just choosing "network drive", so you do not have all problems. Or if you are in a RAID or LVM what do you expect to tell programs?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Why would this information be wrong? In the relevant patch https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1498042 there are some reasons mentioned why the guest needs to know this. For example if the guest creates a btrfs filesystem, then btrfs uses different parameters/optimizations when it knows its on SSD. I dont need to provide any other information (manufacturer, model, etc) because thats not important as the disk is virtual anyway. The only thing that matters is HDD vs SSD.

Comment: Ok. You do as you just wrote. Then the sysadmin will move the docker in a different machine... and you get "wrong setup". It is very general: Do not use docker if you need to be near the hardware. Docker is not for that. Docker is a level of abstraction over physical machine.